# Right click dialog result

Tags: c#, dialog

I'm trying to allow a dialog to be run when the user right clicks a text box within my program. I've seen a few posts similar to this one however, none have worked for me.

I've left my code below, if anyone can give me some insight as to why the program doesn't recognise my right clicks that would be much appreciated

```
private void tbCUSTOMERID_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            switch (e.Button)
            {
                case MouseButtons.Left:
                    break;
                case MouseButtons.Right:
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to search for this customer?", "Customer ID Search", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        int found = Array.BinarySearch(cust, tbCUSTOMERID.Text);

                        if (found < 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Customer found!");
                            tbCUSTOMERID.Text = cust[found].GScID;
                            tbCUSTOMERNAME.Text = cust[found].GSname;
                            tbCITY.Text = cust[found].GSlocation;
                            tbEMAIL.Text = cust[found].GSemail;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                    break;
            }


            /*
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to search for this customer?", "Customer ID Search", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    int found = Array.BinarySearch(cust, tbCUSTOMERID.Text);

                    if(found < 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Customer doesn't exist");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Customer found!");
                        tbCUSTOMERID.Text = cust[found].GScID;
                        tbCUSTOMERNAME.Text = cust[found].GSname;
                        tbCITY.Text = cust[found].GSlocation;
                        tbEMAIL.Text = cust[found].GSemail;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
            */
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [MouseUp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.mouseup) Event instead of MouseClick Event. This would help you get the Mouse Right Click on the Textbox

```
textBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.textBox1_MouseUp);


private void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```